# What's the most efficient UUID column type

Tags: sql-server, mysql, oracle, postgresql, index

For storing a 128 bits UUID there are multiple storage options:

1. a byte[16] column
2. two bigint/long(64 bits) columns
3. a CHAR(36) column - 32 hex digits + 4 dashes.
4. a UUID database specific column, if db supports it

From an indexing point of view which of those are the most efficient? If the db doesn't support a dedicated uuid type which of 1, 2, 3 are the best candidates?

Comment: This is a bit too "it depends" - lots of implementation specifics.

Comment: I would never choose 3: never store something in 36 bytes when it can be done in 16. I use `raw(16)` in Oracle and `uuid` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: the simpler the better.

Comment: `uuid` >>  `bytea` >> `text` with `CHECK` constraint > `varchar(36)` >> `char(36)`. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/3684.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A dedicated `uuid` type is your best bet for PostgreSQL. Hard to say with other DBs - it's not impossible for someone to impliment a `uuid` type that's stored less efficiently than a simple byte type.

Again in PostgreSQL, `bytea` would be a reasonable way to store UUIDs if you didn't have the `uuid` type. For other DBs it depends on how they store binary data.

Where possible I'd strongly avoid using hex-with-dashes. It's way less efficient to compare, sort, and store.

So really, "not (2) or (3)". Ever. Use (4) where supported, (1) otherwise.

Comment: One thing to note is that the PostgreSQL UUID type is not supported natively in arrays or has this been fixed ?
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CE7DAF78.583FD%25martin.petras%40coresystems.ch

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy That's from 2013. It was a minor oversight. `SELECT ARRAY['ef1e0638-072e-4caa-88b3-97bfa5b2e8c3']::uuid[]`

Answer (score 4):

In preference order: 4,1,2,3
Do not use UUIDs as the clustering key if using SQL server as, not only will it fragment badly,  the clustering key is used in all non clustered indexes and you'd add those bytes to each index row. 
Fragmentation can be mitigated by using NEWSEQUENTIALID but usually prefer a bingint identity for your Clustering Key over a GUID to prevent bloat in other indexes.

The difference between choosing 1 over 2 will depend how more efficient the database handles two columns of basic types over a single column fixed array. It should be easy enough to test with dummy data. Look at the speed of your queries as well as the size of indexes and data. Small+fast is the best!

Answer (score 1):

One would have to suppose that any natively-supported data type would be better optimised in the product than anything that could be put together as a client of that product.  After that, whatever has the smallest byte count so you get the maximum rows per page.

Comment: True, but is it that just the byte size that matters? Doesn't the type affect the indexing algorithm?

Comment: @Vlad I use SQL Server.  AFAIK all data types are handled the same when constructing a B-tree (or a hash index for 2104 in-memory).  There are [good reasons](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/effective-clustered-indexes/) to keep this as narrow as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Very late, I know, Vlad. [UUIDv7](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-peabody-dispatch-new-uuid-format-01.html#name-uuidv7-layout-and-bit-order) is excellent for database inserts as it supports decentralized generation as well as efficient clustered index insertion.